# martingale convergence theorem

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability, martingale

Let $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be i.i.d. random variables with density $f$ with respect to Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$, and $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in \mathbb {R}$. $g$ is another density (with respect to Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb {R}$) of some random variable.

Define $Y_n = \frac{\prod_{i=1}^n g(X_i)}{\prod_{i=1}^n f(X_i)}$.

Prove that $Y_n$ converges almost surely to an integrable limit.

I want to prove this problem by martigale/submartingale convergence thereom. But I have difficulty in showing that this $Y_n$ is a martingale with respective to canonical filtration $\mathcal F_n = \sigma(X_1,\dots, X_n)$:

$$\mathbb{E}\left[ Y_{n+1}\mid \mathcal F_n\right] = \mathbb E\left[Y_n\frac{g(X_{n+1})}{f(X_{n+1})}\mid \mathcal F_n \right] = Y_n\mathbb E\left[\frac{g(X_{n+1})}{f(X_{n+1})}\right]$$

Then I do not know how to continue this.

Comment: Write the expectation as an integral over the density of $X_{n+1}$ and simplify the integrand: what do you get?